# CreateReadStream event are not generated properly if there are multiple pipes

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an nodejs application written with electron Framework. I am using multiple pipes to read from, which are used for different purposes. A backend module pushes some data to these pipes and the nodejs module will read it. It seems like because of the multiple pipes the readstream events are not triggered properly.

I have made the following observations

- If the I dont stream the buffer for 'xyz' and 'lmn' files, then I get proper events/data for the 'abc' file. However if I try to stream data from all the files, createreadstream events are not triggered for the first one.
- It seems like the data is being cached somewhere, because when the function is called the next time the data of the previous run is fetched.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function ABC () {
  var fd = fs.openSync('abc','r+')
  readstreamabc = fs.createreadstream(none, {fd:fd});

  readstreamabc.on('data',function () {
    //do something    
  });
}

function XYZ () {
  var fd = fs.openSync('xyz','r+')
  readstreamxyz = fs.createreadstream(none, {fd:fd});

  readstreamxyz.on('data',function () {
    //do something

  });
}

function lmn () {
  var fd = fs.openSync('lmn','r+')
  readstreamlmn = fs.createreadstream(none, {fd:fd});

  readstreamlmn.on('data',function () {
    //do something

  });
}
```

The behavior is observed in Centos

Please help me in understanding why this behaviour is seen.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this meant to be pseduo-code because `fs.createreadstream()` is not a function.  It would be `fs.createReadStream`.

Comment: I don't buy your theory with just this code.  There's likely something else going on that you aren't showing us.   Please show us a runnable block of code (not pseudo-code) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Calling each of these functions starts reading the file again over from the beginning, so of course previous data would be read each time you call one of these functions.

Comment: @jfriend00 it doesn’t read all over again. Once a portion of data is read from the file, that portion is no longer in the file. So seems like it is being cached somewhere.

Comment: If it's a physical file, that's not true.  If you open the file again from scratch, the new stream starts reading from the beginning of the file. That's what your code shows. It shows re-opening the file from scratch and reading from the beginning again.  As I've said, you need to show us your REAL code if you want any real help here.  This pseudo-code does not match what you're saying at all.  FYI, reading data from a physical file does not cause the data to be removed from the file.  That seems to be what you're asserting here.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about the `r+` access mode.  That opens the file for reading and writing and throws an exception if the file does not exist.  It starts reading at the beginning of the file.